# How to add custom modules in the same way of jdbc modules are added?

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, hibernate-search, wildfly-swarm

Today I upgraded my application from 2017.11.0 to 2017.12.1 This is the problem:

My application use hibernate-orm 5.2.12.Final and hibernate-search 5.8.2.Final. Because wildfly-swarm has different version of hibernate I decided to use maven-dependency-plugin to add hibernate modules to the same folder where jdbc modules are added:

Like this tutorial said: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/topical/html_single/wildfly/Wildfly.html

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>unpack</id>
            <phase>generate-resources</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>unpack</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <artifactItems>
                    <artifactItem>
                        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                        <artifactId>hibernate-orm-modules</artifactId>
                        <version>5.2.12.Final</version>
                        <classifier>wildfly-11-dist</classifier>
                        <type>zip</type>
                        <overWrite>false</overWrite>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}/modules</outputDirectory>
                    </artifactItem>
                    <artifactItem>
                        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                        <artifactId>hibernate-search-modules</artifactId>
                        <version>5.8.2.Final</version>
                        <classifier>wildfly-11-dist</classifier>
                        <type>zip</type>
                        <overWrite>false</overWrite>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}/modules</outputDirectory>
                    </artifactItem>
                </artifactItems>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

and on persistence.xml I added these properties:

It worked very well. It seems that in wildfly-swarm 2017.11.0 all folders and files located under /modules folder were added as part of wildfly modules.

After upgrade to wildfly-swarm 2017.12.1 my configuration doesn't work anymore, because wildly-swarm is just detecting jdbc modules and is not detecting the hibernate modules I added.

Has something changed related to the way wildfly-swarm detects custom modules in wildfly-swarm 2017.12.1?
How could I use custom version of hibernate on wildfly-swarm?

Comment: I suspect the change you're noticing is due to 2017.12.1 being based on WF 11 and not WF 10.

The change from WF 10 to WF 11 changes some of the semantics around module definitions to begin to cater for JDK 9.

It may also be necessary to modify some of the module dependencies for your custom module.xml files as they may be different for WF 11

Comment: It might be. I've published the same question to Google Groups here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/wildfly-swarm/7MvwxAuVQBk and  I prepared a very basic test on this github repository https://github.com/carlosthe19916/wildfly-swarm-hibernate The master branch is using wildfly-swarm:2017.11.0 and there is another branch called 2017.12.1. I'll take a look to wildffly 11 documentation and maybe I'll find the mistake